# How to send actions from one ViewController to another ViewController (active together)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-maps

I know this question has been asked so many many times. But here the scenario is changed. I am using [MMParallaxView](https://github.com/MillmanY/MMParallaxView) and that looks pretty awesome.

But Now at this point, I want to communicate between these two View controllers. Let me tell you that this github code helps us to make a view like ios Map App. I mean you can have Map (as 1st view controller) and you can have a list of places view controller on top of 1st View Controller. Just same like Map app.

Now I want to click on the UITableView cell and want to navigate on map. For this I know how to catch delegated method. And I am successfully getting of taps on the UItableView cell. But How to send that clicked item data to 1stView Controller so that It can show or mark selected area on Map.

I know this can also be done. But how?

Comment: Use delegation pattern

Comment: @SPatel in this library I am unable to use the delegation pattren. Please check out the Library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the example app for MMParallaxView...

---

In `ChildBottomViewController.swift`

Add this at the top (outside of the class):

```
protocol CellTapDelegate {
    func didSelectRow(indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

Add this line at the beginning of the class:

```
var cellTapDelegate: CellTapDelegate?
```

Change `didSelectRowAt` function to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

        self?.cellTapDelegate?.didSelectRow(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

---

In `MapViewController.swift`

Change the class declaration to:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CellTapDelegate {
```

and add this function:

```
@objc func didSelectRow(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Delegate got didSelectRow for: \(indexPath)")
}
```

---

Then, in `SecondViewController.swift`

Add this at the end of `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    var mapVC: MapViewController?
    var bottomVC: ChildBottomViewController?

    for vc in self.childViewControllers {
        if vc is MapViewController {
            mapVC = vc as? MapViewController
        } else if vc is ChildBottomViewController {
            bottomVC = vc as? ChildBottomViewController
        }
    }

    // if we found valid child view controllers, set the delegate
    if mapVC != nil && bottomVC != nil {
        bottomVC?.cellTapDelegate = mapVC
    }
```

---

Now, selecting a row from the "slide up from bottom" table view will send the selected indexPath to its delegate - the map view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol CellTapDelegate {
  func didTapOnItem(obj: MyObject)
}
class MyViewControllerContainingTheTableView : UIViewcontroller {
weak var delegate: CellTapDelegate?
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
         didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let item = arrayOfObjects[indexpath.row]
  self.delegate.didTapOnItem(item)
}
}
//View Controller where you you will have the listner
class FirstViewController : UIViewController {
  func setupParalax() {
// you have to modify this according to your need
  let vc = MyViewControllerContainingTheTableView()
  vc.delegate = self

}
}
extension FirstViewController: CellTapDelegate {
  func didTapOnItem(obj: MyObject) {
  // you have your required object here
}
}
```

Comment: I do not think so it will work. Did you know about the library I shared above

Comment: No I don't have knowledge about the library. My answer is based upon how basic delegation works

Comment: yes I know,  but that can not implementable, Since these two (1st and 2nd viewControllers) are initiated by 1 separate view controller

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible by implementing your own delegate, but my knowledge of MMParrallaxView is that there is only 1 view controller which displays two views meaning the view controller should be able to pass things between the two views as it is. In this case the view controller would implement the table view delegate methods and add the table view to the bottom view. Then add the map to the top view. This should allow you to catch the table view cell selection and update the map in the top view accordingly.

Example based on the structure I believe you are using:

```
public class FirstViewController {

    public let parallaxView = MMParallaxView()
    private var secondViewController: SecondViewController
    private var thirdViewController: ThirdViewController

    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        thirdViewController = ThirdViewController()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(parallaxView)
        thirdViewController.delegate = secondViewController

        parallaxView.parallaxTopView = secondViewController.view
        self.addChildViewController(secondViewController)
        secondViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        parallaxView.parallaxBottomView = thirdViewController.view
        self.addChildViewController(thirdViewController)
        thirdViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}

public class SecondViewController: ThirdViewControllerDelegate {

    public func updateMap() {
        // Update map
    }
}

public class ThirdViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    weak var delegate ThirdViewControllerDelegate?

    private var table: UITableView = UITableView()

    open override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.updateMap()
    }

}

protocol ThirdViewControllerDelegate: class {
    public func updateMap() {}
}
```

if the view controllers are instantiated through the Storyboard then you can try this:

```
public class MasterViewController {

    var secondViewController: SecondViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MMParallaxTop", sender: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MMParallaxBottom", sender: nil)
    }

    override open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController = secondVC
        }
        if let thirdVC = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController, let second = secondViewController {
            thirdVC.delegate = second
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this Idea, but since as there are 3 viewControllers involved, e.g: MainViewController (which will start 2 more viewcontroller as 1st and 2nd) 
1stViewController (This shows Map)
2ndViewController (This shows UiTableView on top of 1stViewController and you can move it up and down on 1stViewController)

So I am really having no guess to how to forward events(delegate of 1 VC to 2nd VC)

Comment: The second view controller will need to create a delegate protocol that the first view controller (holding the map) will assign itself as the delegate. Once the second view controller catches the cell selection it will need to call the delegate method to update the map.

Comment: but keep in mind that 1st view controller is not starting the 2nd view controller. Will it still work>

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of what I believe to be your structure, I apologise if it is not accurate.

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: This is not the way I initialized my view Controller. The library initialized them in different way

Comment: getting error on these lines 
parallaxView.parallaxTopView = secondViewController
        parallaxView.parallaxBottomView = thirdViewController

Comment: I edited it to add child view controllers properly, I am not entirely familiar with the library you are using so I am not sure how much more help I can offer.

Comment: just try this lib, its small

Comment: well I am doing it by making function in 2ndVC like updateMap()
and in 3rd vc I have done this 
let 2ndVC = 2ndViewController()
and in on tap of cell I am calling 
2ndVC.updateMap() 
is it ok ?

Comment: I won't be able to give it ago at the moment, but the idea is that both of the child view controllers are being created and assigned in the mast view controller so you will need to assign the delegate wherever this is happening in your code as long as you have created the delegate protocol on the view controller with the table view.

Comment: No this will create a separate instance of the second view controller and wont call the displayed one if it has already been created in the master view controller. Think of every let 2ndVC = 2ndViewController() as a unique instance of the view controller.

Comment: as you assigned the views of the 2st and 3rd view controller in the parallax view, it is still crashing . bcz in 3rd view controller it is unable to find it views, i.e UITableView

Comment: Hmm, I am unsure what your code looks like, but what I have supplied is the skeleton of roughly what you will need. I am also unsure of your experience with SWIFT and iOS development, so I am unsure to what level I should explain and offer information. Without seeing your code I am not sure I can do much more.

Comment: actually it is not working, not even showing the UI , lets just forget about delegate, but by just adding views, 2nd and 3rd as you did , not showing anything but white scree

Comment: please have a look, at these lines, in library sample he is adding the VCs (2nd and 3rd) with these 
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MMParallaxTop", sender: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MMParallaxBottom", sender: nil)

Comment: The example found in the library you have linked used the storyboard to create the view controllers and segues between view controllers.

Comment: yes it creates that in storyboard. So cant I hook up when it is passing the segue and pass the delegate

Comment: I will update my example above, but I am unsure if it will work.